# MATLAB: error when importing matlab.io.fits

Tags: matlab, fits

I am trying to create .fits files using the matlab.io.fits functions, following the example given here: [matlab.io.fits.createFile](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.fits.createfile.html).

However, this gives me the following error:

```
>> import matlab.io.*
>> fptr = fits.createFile('myfile.fits');
??? Undefined variable "fits" or class "fits.createFile".
```

Importing the fits class directly also gives an error:

```
>> import matlab.io.fits
??? Import argument 'matlab.io.fits' cannot be found or cannot be imported
```

I get the same result in Matlab2009 and 2015.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to install a specific class? I am new to Matlab, so it might be a very easy mistake, but some of my more Matlab proficient colleagues has not been able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicate that the function cannot be found. This is usually caused by the MATLAB path being corrupted. You can restore it with:

```
>> restoredefaultpath
>> rehash toolboxcache
```

You can figure out if the file is found by executing:

```
>> which -all matlab.io.fits.createFile
```

The file should be in `<matlabroot>/toolbox/matlab/imagesci/+matlab/+io/+fits/createFile.m`. If it is not there, you probably need to reinstall MATLAB.